# iOS QR code generation memory usage

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory, ios8

I have implemented a QR code generator in my app using the following code:

```
+ (UIImage *)qrCodeForString:(NSString *)qrString withScale:(CGFloat)scale {
    CIImage *image = [self createQRForString:qrString];
    return [self createNonInterpolatedUIImageFromCIImage:image withScale:scale];
}

+ (UIImage *)createNonInterpolatedUIImageFromCIImage:(CIImage *)image withScale:(CGFloat)scale
{
    // Render the CIImage into a CGImage
    CGImageRef cgImage = [[CIContext contextWithOptions:nil] createCGImage:image fromRect:image.extent];

    // Now we'll rescale using CoreGraphics
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSizeMake(image.extent.size.width * scale, image.extent.size.width * scale));
    CGContextRef context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // We don't want to interpolate (since we've got a pixel-correct image)
    CGContextSetInterpolationQuality(context, kCGInterpolationNone);
    CGContextDrawImage(context, CGContextGetClipBoundingBox(context), cgImage);
    // Get the image out
    UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    // Tidy up
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
    CGImageRelease(cgImage);
    return scaledImage;
}

+ (CIImage *)createQRForString:(NSString *)qrString
{
    // Need to convert the string to a UTF-8 encoded NSData object
    NSData *stringData = [qrString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"Size: %zd", stringData.length);
    // Create the filter
    CIFilter *qrFilter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIQRCodeGenerator"];
    // Set the message content and error-correction level
    [qrFilter setValue:stringData forKey:@"inputMessage"];
    [qrFilter setValue:@"L" forKey:@"inputCorrectionLevel"];

    // Send the image back
    return qrFilter.outputImage;
}
```

The problem is that if I call the method `+ (UIImage *)qrCodeForString:(NSString *)qrString withScale:(CGFloat)scale` with a long string (but still far within the limit of what a QR code can contain), the memory usage goes crazy! On real devices the app (or the whole device) just crashes, but in a simulator, where I can use all the memory of the computer, it goes up to more than 1 GB for a brief moment while the QR code is generated (then dropping back to normal, with no obvious traces of memory leaks). Is there something wrong with my code, or has Apple implemented APIs with ridiculous memory usage?

An example string that will produce a memory use of 643.7 MB: `1234567890qesgyujfghjkoiuyhgfrty¬˙∫ç∂∆˚¨¥©√∂†¥˙˜˚˙©ƒ∂®†`

Running this code results in the following memory usage:
Before generating QR code: 49.2 MB
While generating QR code: 643.7 MB
After generating QR code: 49.4 MB (some memory is now also used to show the image on the screen)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the issue in the end. Instead of passing the ratio between the screen width and original image size when scaling the image, I passed the screen width, making the image 750x750 times larger. This obviously caused a huge demand for memory. On simple QR codes (short strings), this had no visible effect because the original image was so small, but when the QR code got bigger, the scaling got way more resource demanding as well.

Answer (score 0):

Time to run Instruments using the allocations instrument and see if you can figure out what is causing the huge spike in memory use.